# Irish passport application - parental signatures do not match

Tags: passports, children, ireland

Does anyone know if the requirements around parental signatures on child Irish passport applications/renewals?

**Background:** I recently submitted my daughter's renewal application for her passport only to have it returned with a fresh copy of the parental consent section because her father's signature has changed from the previous application, 9 years ago.

I had assumed that the reason for witnessing the signature was to ensure that the person who signs the form is actually who he/she says he/she is.

Comment: Contact the Passport Office about this. In general, they would reasonably expect signatures of the same person to be similar over time.

Comment: It would seem the least effort solution would simply be to resign using the same signature you used 9 years ago.